# Resetting network interfaces

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, eth0

I am using vmware workstation to create virtual network. Many of the virtual machines are using 3-4 network interfaces. I also wanted to put ubuntu 9.10 OS in two different places. Hence I cloned ubuntu OS. After cloning network interface number in the new machine is starting from eth5. Is there any way to reset so that network interface number starts from eth0?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file which ties the MAC address of your NICs to the interface names.

The mappings from your original VM will carry over to the new VM which is why it thinks eth0-4 are already in use.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the answer. I deleted all the entries in the said file and restarted the system.